# Elastic Search with Skaffold

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eks-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eks
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eks
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.1

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eks-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: eks
  ports:
    - name: eks-db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
```

I use this code for setting up Elastic Search for my project through skaffold. But when I try to connect to the elastic search running on port 9200 it gives me back an error that the connection has been refused.

```
const client: NewTypes = new Client({
      node: 'http://localhost:9200'
    })

    interface Source {
      foo: string
    }
    const request: estypes.IndexRequest<Source> = {
      index: 'test',
      body: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }

    }
    await client.index(request);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch needs a Persistent Volume to work.

Also, the configuration you wrote looks like its for a database like MongoDB or PostgresSQL.
Elasticsearch is not a database. It's a tool for managing, scaling and analysing big data. So, its configuration would be way different from any database.

You should be installing Elastic Cloud on your system using the following command

- [Official documentation for installing ElasticCloud](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html)
- [Managing Elastic Cluster Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-elasticsearch.html)

```
kubectl create -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.0.0/crds.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://download.elastic.co/downloads/eck/2.0.0/operator.yaml
```

After you apply Elastic Cloud files to Kubernetes you can deploy a elastic cluster with the following configuration file.

```yaml
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 8.0.1
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

I would recommend you also [visit](https://www.codding.in/read/f2cd374fbfdf4deaa5dc59b9bf960560)

Also, please go through Helm Charts documentation of how to setup Elasticsearch because it just takes one simple line to get Elastic search on your cluster.
I am leaving this [link](https://www.codding.in/read/08efe51b0a0a43728d59484f5086d422) for your reference if in case you have any doubts how to setup Elasticsearch with helm